# thrift timeout for long run call: thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes

Tags: python, sockets, timeout, thrift

I've build some a rpc service using thrift. It may run long time (minutes to hours) for each call. I've set the thrift timeout to 2 days.

```
transport = TSocket.TSocket(self.__host, self.__port)
transport.setTimeout(2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

But the thrift always closes connection after about 600s, with the following exception:

```
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

Is there's any other timeout should i set? (python, thrift server: windows; client: ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The Thrift Transport connection is being disconnected. This could be due to network issues or remote service restart or time out issues. Whenever any call is made after a disconnect this results in TTransportException. This problem can be solved by reconnecting to the remote service. 
Try using this, invoking it before making a remote service call.

```
def repoen_transport():
    try:
        if not transport.isOpen():
            transport.open()
    except Exception, msg:
        print >> sys.stderr.write("Error reopening transport {}".format(msg))
```